# Multi Dimensional Array in Scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala

I am new to Scala and have run into a problem defining multi-dimensional arrays.

I have tried the following type specifications that did not compile:

```
val shortfall: Array[Array[Int]]= new Array (6,248)  
val shortfall= new  Array.ofDim[Int] (6,248)
```

The following specification compiled but does not allocate an instance of the array. The 
type spec for parameter passing was  `Array[Array[Int]]`.

```
val shortfall=  Array.ofDim[Int] (6,248)
```

I am converting a modeling application from Java  with the following definition

```
int[][] shortfall = new int[6][248]
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to have a look at the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$)

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> Array.ofDim[Int](6,248)
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, ...))
```